Changing default system font of Android emulator
We are trying to replicate a bug we found for a specific device. It seems to be a font issue so we are checking for a way to change the default system font of the Android emulator.
I already tried changing the font.xml from the sdk directly but it seems to be not working.

To change the default system font in the Android emulator, you can try the following methods:
Using Developer option:
Some Android emulators allow font scaling adjustments via Developer Options. To check if you can tweak the font size:
Go to Settings → System → Developer Options (if it's enabled).
Look for "Minimum width" or "Font size". This can help mimic different font settings but may not apply to the entire system font.

Hi thanks for the answer. However, is there a way to change the actual font of the the emulator itself? From what I heard the default font of and Android is Roboto so I'm finding a way to change the font to another besides the default one.
